# I want to open 2 windows on 1 click

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which opens a window and have a javascript which also opens another window and i want to open boths windows on one click.

```
'<script type="text/javascript">function clickme() { window.open('http://www.google.com/'); } </script>'

'<a href="#" onclick="clickme();">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.clicmanager.fr/exe.php?c=17346&s=29646&t=1&q="></script></a>'
```

But unfortunately only the ad is opening and google is not opening. Please help me, I want to open both windows on one click. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm.... what about

```
function clickme()
      {
      window.open('http://www.google.com/');
      window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');          
      }
```

it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Call `window.open` function two times in your function:

```
window.open('url_one', 'win1', 'settings');
window.open('url_two', 'win2', 'settings');

function clickme(){
    window.open('http://www.google.com', 'google');
    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', 'yahoo');
}
```

Comment: As you can see my second URL is not a site, it's a javascript already :
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.clicmanager.fr/exe.php?c=17346&s=29646&t=1&q="></script>

It's basically a banner ad and I want to open another window when someone clicks on this ad.

Comment: @Rizwan Aaqil: You just specify the `src` value in window.open. Let me know if you still have problem.